# I extruded the edges, and I want to return to the initial shape

Tags: modifiers, bevel, extrude

I would like what I have selected to go back to how it was before? But how to do it ? so that there is no extrusion and it is just a smooth shape

[image]

like this
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: with decimate it's not pretty*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could select the faces ring, then press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*:

[image]

Then increase the threshold in the *Operator Box* until the vertices merge:

[image]

If you want an even space between the vertices, select the edges (you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to quickly select the whole edge loops) and right click > *LoopTools* (you need to enable the *LoopTools* addon) > *Space*:

[image]

Don't forget to remove the inner faces that it has left: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *(Select Similar) > Perimeter* to select them all, then <kbd>X</kbd> to remove:

[image]

**EDIT:** From your version, merge by distance with a value of 0.038:

[image]

Select the top and bottom edge loops and *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Remove the inner faces:

[image]

Comment: that's perfect, thank you, it will help a lot of people

Comment: Also don't forget to remove the inner faces at the end, see my edit

Comment: but it's breaking my mesh, look at the 3rd image :/

Comment: Please share your object (before the operation)

Comment: it's done, can you go see please

Comment: don't you have a previous version? Also why don't you simply use a cylinder? is it not supposed to be the metal ring?

Comment: no, in fact I've already found it, but I wanted to know how to fix a shape, but otherwise I've already found it, but I wouldn't be able to fix it if the shape was more complex

Comment: I've edited my answer, I was able to fix your version